# Writing a select query

Tags: group-by, oracle10g, inner-join

I have two tables:

```
  table1 =tbl_main:

  item_id fastec_qty
   001       102
   002       200
   003       300
   004       400

  table2= tbl_dOrder
    order_id    item_id     amount
     1001          001      30
     1001          002      40
     1002          001      50
     1002          003      70
```

How can I write a query so that the result of the tables are as follows:

```
  item_id       amount   difference  
    001         102      22 
    002         200      160
    003         300      230 
    004         400      400
```

The difference between the amount in table 1 and the total amounts disbursed from the Table 2.

Comment: Why did you tag your question as `c#`. Do you need it in linq?

Comment: I want to show the results in datagridview control .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT q.item_id, a.fastec_qty AS amount, a.fastec_qty - q.amount AS difference
FROM (
    SELECT item_id, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM tbl_dOrder
    GROUP BY item_id
) q
    JOIN tbl_main a ON a.item_id = q.item_id
```

Here this query is going to first SUM the amounts from `tbl2` grouped by the `item_id`, then it's going to `JOIN` the results of that query with the first table so it can do the calculation for the difference column.